# ASP.NET how to call clientscript from public static method

Tags: asp.net, static-methods

I'm going to use following ClientScript function (VS2010,C#) in a public static method, but it gives me some errors (I want to use it for response redirect with "_parent" target

```
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Load", "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.location.href = '" + a + "'; </script>");

Error   37  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript.get' 

Error   38  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'object.GetType()'
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use instance properties (`ClientScript`) or methods (`GetType()`) inside a [static methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (basically anything instance).

Drop the static keyword and it should work:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
     ClientScript.RegisterSomeScript("Load", 
        "<script>....</script>");
}
```

EDIT after comment:

Or if you need that the method is static in a static class pass the Page object as a parameter:

```
public static class ScriptRegistar
{
    public static void RegisterSomeScript(Page page)
    {
         page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript("Load", 
        "<script>.........</script>");
    }
}
```

Usage (inside a page codebehind):

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ScriptRegistar.RegisterSomeScript(this);
}
```

Side note: `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` takes two arguments: the key for the script, and script text, so there is no need for the `GetType()` there.

Comment: oh thanks for your description but how can I pass (Page) to my function? I'm going to define a public static function in a public static class that is globally accessible in all files, so how can I pass page object to this function from other files?

Comment: can I call the function in this way: ._Default.MyUtilityFunctions.LogoutUser(Page);? my public static class is MyUtilityFunctions and it is defines in Default.aspx.cs file, it gave me no error, so can I rely on it?

Comment: This sollution helped me . Thank you :-)